# Iterating through pandas dataframe while keeping memory of earlier states

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Following is the dataframe I have. `JourneyGroup` is my expected column.

```
    Day  Journey  InitialValue  Value  JourneyGroup
0    12        1           3.0      4             1
1    12        1           4.0      5             1
2    12        0           NaN      7             1
3    12        0           NaN      2             1
4    12        1           5.0      8             2
5    12        0           NaN      9             2
6    13        1           3.0      4             3
7    13        1           4.0      5             3
8    13        0           NaN      7             3
9    13        0           NaN      6             3
10   13        1           1.0      2             3
11   13        0           NaN      9             0
```

If `Journey == 1`, that indicates the beginning of a journey. As long as a  `Journey` is ON, no other `Journey` can start in the same `Day` in the subsequent rows. A `Journey` will end if current row `Value < InitialValue(from the first row of a journey)`. Once a start and end is identified for a `Journey`, a group number is assigned in `JourneyGroup` grouped by `Day`.

For example, in the first row, `Journey ==1`, then the `Journey` starts. In the second row, it is also `Journey==1`, but a `Journey` is already ON from the first row, so as of 2nd row, it is just the continuation of the first `Journey` from the 1st row. On the 4th row, `Value of 2 < InitialValue of 3`, which marks the end of the `Journey` and `JourneyGroup` of 1 is assigned.

I can use `ngroup` or `pd.categorical` to assign groups and check condition
by doing something like:
`df.Value<df.groupby(['Group??']).InitialValue.transform('first')` but not sure how to iteratively put together the concepts while keeping memory on whether a `Journey` is ON or OFF.

N.B:- A `Journey` cannot span multiple days and has to end in the same day just like `Journey2` ended even when `Value` was always greater than `InitialValue`.

Comment: post your expected output

Comment: @pyd My expected output is the `JourneyGroup` column.

Comment: It looks like your expected output violates your very first condition, that no other Journey can start in the same Day. It looks like Journey 1 and 2 both start on Day 12 in your expected output column...

Comment: @rahlf23 Journey 2 starts in the same day because Journey 1 ends in the 4th row. I will edit the language a little to make it more clear. Thank you.

Comment: One more thing, can a Journey span multiple Days?

Comment: @rahlf23 A `Journey` cannot span multiple days and has to end in the same day just like `Journey2` ended even if its conditions were always ON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one try, there needs to be more data to test:

```
t_num = ((df['Value'].shift() < df.groupby(['Day',df.groupby('Day')['Journey'].cummax()])['Value'].transform('first')) | df['Day'].diff().bfill().ne(0)).cumsum() + 1
m = t_num.diff().bfill().eq(1) & df.Journey.eq(0)
t_num = t_num.mask(m,0)
df['JGroup'] = t_num
df
```

Output:

```
    Day  Journey  InitialValue  Value  JourneyGroup  JGroup
0    12        1           3.0      4             1       1
1    12        1           4.0      5             1       1
2    12        0           NaN      7             1       1
3    12        0           NaN      2             1       1
4    12        1           5.0      8             2       2
5    12        0           NaN      9             2       2
6    13        1           3.0      4             3       3
7    13        1           4.0      5             3       3
8    13        0           NaN      7             3       3
9    13        0           NaN      6             3       3
10   13        1           1.0      2             3       3
11   13        0           NaN      9             0       0
```

Explanation:

Groupby Day and find the start of a trip and set all days in that day as on Journey since we are not sure when the trip stops:

```
df.groupby('Day')['Journey'].cummax()
```

Next, use that in a new groupby to find the first value at the start of a trip and copy it along the length of the groups using transform.

```
df.groupby(['Day',df.groupby('Day')['Journey'].cummax()])['Value'].transform('first')
```

Use, shift to compare with the next record.  If comparision is less than, the return True or if the date changes return True, this indicates end of old journey and start of new.  Use `cumsum` to increment counter.

Next using that count index, need to mask out the record that starts a new group with journey = 0.

```
m = t_num.diff().bfill().eq(1) & df.Journey.eq(0)
t_num = t_num.mask(m,0)
```

This really is just a start.  I don't feel that this code is roboust enough to hand a different dataset.

Comment: you are a wizard with pandas. The answer would be more digestible if you could break it down with some explanations. Thank you for the great solution.